# Wide and short ytableau

Tags: macros, ytableau

I'd like to draw a Youngtableau with entries given by a formula. The formula is not super long, but in order to fit it, I have to increase the boxsize to 6em. Then it is quite tall and has lots of unnecessary space above and below it.

Is there a way to change the height of a box without changing the width? I see  `\vrule@normal@YT` in the [documentation](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ytableau/ytableau.pdf), but I'm not sure how to use it. I have heard that one should not use variables which include an `@` in the name. But even if I should use that command, I'm not sure how to use it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}
\ytableausetup{boxsize=6em}
\begin{ytableau}
\none & \none & \none & 1 \\
\none & \none & \none & 2 \\
\none & \none & \none & \vdots \\
\none & \none & \none & d-2i-1\\
d-2i & d-2i & \cdots & d-2i \\
d-2i+1 & d-2i+1 & \cdots & d-2i+i\\
d-2i+2 \\
\vdots\\
d-2i+m
\end{ytableau}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome! In the future, please always make your code compilable. Include the document class and `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}` (as well as any packages and relevant code). This is so other users only need to copy and paste your code. You'll generally get more responses. I added the missing information for you.

Answer (score 2):

To provide another option, instead of the `ytableau` package, you could use `nicematrix`.

[image]

The option `hvlines` draws horizontal and vertical rules, but `corners` excludes the empty corners. `columns-width=auto` sets all column widths to the widest column. `cell-space-limits=-5pt` reduces the vertical padding for each cell. `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` is large enough for all rows to have the same height.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceArray}{cccc}[hvlines, corners, columns-width=auto, cell-space-limits=-5pt]
&&&1\\
&&&2\\
&&&\vdots\\
&&&d-2i-1\\
d-2i & d-2i & \cdots & d-2i\\
d-2i+1 & d-2i+1 & \cdots & d-2i+i\\
d-2i+2\\
\vdots\\
d-2i+m
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `\scalebox` of the graphicx-package is your friend:

Just vertically (down)scale the entire ytableau  while vertically (up)scaling each entry by the inverse factor.

You also need to adjust the vertical placement of entries by lowering them by half of the difference between the height of a `\mathstrut` after upscaling and the normal hight of a `\mathstrut`.

Drawback of this workaround: Heights of horizontal rules will be slightly different from widths of vertical rules.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}


\newlength\scratchlength
\newcommand\s[2]{% #1 - (up)scale-factor; #2 = content
  \settoheight\scratchlength{\mathstrut}%
  \scratchlength=\number\numexpr\number#1-1\relax\scratchlength
%  \scratchlength=\number\numexpr\number#1-1\relax\ht\strutbox
  \lower.5\scratchlength\hbox{\scalebox{1}[#1]{$#2$}}%
}

% Default is 1.5em.
% Let's vertically upscale content and boxes by (up)scale-factor 4 (4x1.5em = 6em).
% Let's vertically downscale the entire ytableau by (down)scale-factor 1/4 =.25.

\ytableausetup{boxsize=6em}%
\scalebox{1}[.25]{%
\begin{ytableau}
\none & \none & \none & \s{4}{1} \\
\none & \none & \none & \s{4}{2} \\
\none & \none & \none & \s{4}{\vdots}\\
\none & \none & \none & \s{4}{d-2i-1} \\
\s{4}{d-2i} & \s{4}{d-2i} & \s{4}{\cdots} & \s{4}{d-2i} \\
\s{4}{d-2i+1g} & \s{4}{d-2i+1} & \s{4}{\cdots} & \s{4}{d-2i+i}\\
\s{4}{d-2i+2} \\
\s{4}{\vdots}\\
\s{4}{d-2i+m}
\end{ytableau}
}%


\ytableausetup{boxsize=normal}%
\begin{ytableau}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & \none &\vdots\\
3 & \cdots & \none & 3
\end{ytableau}

\end{document}
```

[image]